# Write a method called AddUp100 which takes in one value (an integer) and returns the sum of the next 100 numbers (int)

Tags: java, eclipse

Write a method called AddUp100 which takes in one value (an integer) and returns the sum of the next 100 numbers (int) on completion of the method.  It does not consider the starting number, just the next 100 numbers.  The method will return an int.

The method accepts any integer (positive or negative) which in the int range and prints out the addition of the next 100 numbers.  It then returns the answer as an integer

Note: it only prints out the sum of the numbers.

So if 12 was entered, the program would print out

i.e. the program would add up 13+14+15+...+ 112. = 6250

This is my try:

```
private static int AddUp100(int input) {
    input = input + 1;
    int sum  = input;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        sum  = sum + i; 
        System.out.println("Sum in loop is: " + sum);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    return input;
}
```

}

**Second edit - It shows the correct adding up of numbers, however how do i tell the program to add only the next 100 numbers not more ?**

```
private static int AddUp100(int input) {
    int sum  = 0;
    input = input + 1;
    System.out.println("input before loop " + input);
    
    for (int i = input ; i < 100; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
        System.out.println("Sum:  " + sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hint: In a loop the initial value of the variable does not have to be zero.

Comment: The result can be calculated using [Gauss formula](https://study.com/academy/lesson/finding-the-sum-of-consecutive-numbers.html) without looping.

Comment: How do you handle an input that results in a sum > Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: @PM77-1 the practice question requires it to be with a loop, with either for or while loop.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why I posted my hint first.

Comment: @PM77-1 how to tell program to only count next 100 numbers? (see new code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can simplified to

```
    long sum = 0;
    long input = 12;
    for (int loop = input + 1; loop <= input + 100; loop++ ) 
        sum += loop;
    
    System.out.println(sum);
```

**output**

```
    6250
```

As you can start with any `int` value, then it would be better to store the sum and input in a long value to prevent Integer overflow i.e. Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1

Answer (score 0):

Just write a for loop that runs 100 times. Within the loop, add the current input to the sum and increment the input by 1.

```
private static int AddUp100(int input) {
    int sum  = 0;
    input = input + 1;
    System.out.println("input before loop " + input);
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++) {
        sum += input;
        input += 1
        System.out.println("Sum:  " + sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Been at it for the last 3 hours, thanks for your help! My reputation doesn't allow me to up-vote unfortunately. It finally worked :)